# Search through array with 'containing' rather than 'equal to'

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I have some code that searches through one of my arrays, and it works great, however I would now like to modify it slightly.

Basically, at the moment it searches through a list of attractions by their name. I would like to change this so that it searches through by name, but not the entire name, just if it contains the search string.

This is my current code:

```
func getRideByName(name: String) -> Ride? {
    //Returns ride by name or nil if not found

    let result = self.rideArray.filter({
        $0.name == name
    })
    return result.count == 0 ? nil : result[0]
}
```

How can I change this code to find attraction names that contain the search string?

**EDIT**

Here is how the contents of the `rideArray`:

```
class Ride: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var waitTime: String?
    var longitude: Double?
    var latitude: Double?
    var updated: NSDate?
    var fastPass: Bool?
    var disabledAccess: Bool?
    var singleRider: Bool?
    var heightRestriction: Bool?
    var rideDescription: String?
    var hasWaitTime: Bool?
    var rideImage: String?
    var rideImageSmall: String?
    var mustSee: Bool?
    var isLive: Bool?

    init(name: String?, waitTime: String?, longitude: Double?, latitude: Double?, updated: NSDate?, fastPass: Bool?, disabledAccess: Bool?, singleRider: Bool?, heightRestriction: Bool?, rideDescription: String?, hasWaitTime: Bool?, rideImage: String?, rideImageSmall: String?, mustSee: Bool?, isLive: Bool?) {
        self.name = name
        self.waitTime = waitTime
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.updated = updated
        self.fastPass = fastPass
        self.disabledAccess = disabledAccess
        self.singleRider = singleRider
        self.heightRestriction = heightRestriction
        self.rideDescription = rideDescription
        self.hasWaitTime = hasWaitTime
        self.rideImage = rideImage
        self.rideImageSmall = rideImageSmall
        self.mustSee = mustSee
        self.isLive = isLive
    }
}

for object in objects {
    var ride = Ride(
        name: object.objectForKey("Name") as? String,
        waitTime: object.objectForKey("WaitTime") as? String,
        longitude: object.objectForKey("Longitude") as? Double,
        latitude: object.objectForKey("Latitude") as? Double,
        updated: object.updatedAt as NSDate?,
        fastPass: object.objectForKey("FastPass") as? Bool,
        disabledAccess: object.objectForKey("DisabledAccess") as? Bool,
        singleRider: object.objectForKey("SingleRider") as? Bool,
        heightRestriction: object.objectForKey("HeightRestriction") as? Bool,
        rideDescription: object.objectForKey("RideDescription") as? String,
        hasWaitTime: object.objectForKey("HasWaitTime") as? Bool,
        rideImage:(object.objectForKey("RideImage") as? PFFile)?.url,
        rideImageSmall:(object.objectForKey("RideImageSmall") as? PFFile)?.url,
        mustSee: object.objectForKey("MustSee") as? Bool,
        isLive: false)
    self.rideArray.append(ride)
}
```

Comment: Change the filter block to see if one string is a substring of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Recap

Looking at your code it looks that:

```
let rideArray : [Ride]
```

(maybe `var` but does not matter now).

I also see that `Ride` is a `class` or a `struct` having a property `name` of type `String?`.

```
struct Ride {
    let name: String?
}
```

Finally your class has e property named `rideArray` of type `[Ride]`.

```
class Foo {
    let rideArray : [Ride]

}
```

### Here's the solution

```
class Foo {
    let rideArray : [Ride] = [Ride(name: "one"), Ride(name: "two"), Ride(name: "three")]

    // Important: there is a much better implementation of this method at the end of this answer
    func getRideByName(name: String) -> Ride? {
        return rideArray.filter { $0.name?.rangeOfString(name) != nil }.first
    }
}
```

### Test

```
Foo().getRideByName("one") // {name "one"}
Foo().getRideByName("on") // {name "one"}
Foo().getRideByName("o") // {name "one"}
Foo().getRideByName("wrong") // nil
Foo().getRideByName("the") // {name "three"}
```

Hope this helps.

### Update

In the comment below, user **Qbyte** suggested to use `indexOf` instead of `filter` inside the `getRideByName` method for performance improvements reasons.

**Qbyte is totally right.**

Infact my initial implementation was iterating all the elements in `rideArray` (even when the matching element was the first one!). This was an unnecessary waste of resources and time.

Instead it is a plausible assumption that the `indexOf` method does iterate until the matching element is found. No more.

From Official Documentation of `indexOf`:

> Returns the first index where predicate returns true for the
>   corresponding value, or nil if such value is not found.

This is a much better implementation of `getRideByName` and you should use this.

```
func getRideByName(name: String) -> Ride? {
    if let index = ( rideArray.indexOf { return $0.name?.rangeOfString(name) != nil}) {
        return rideArray[index]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the solution and also the explanation.

Comment: Instead of `filter` I would suggest to use `indexOf` which is more efficient and then map it to the according element.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string is a substring of another string, you could use the `containsString` method:

```
func getRideByName(name: String) -> Ride? {
    //Returns ride by name or nil if not found

    let result = self.rideArray.filter({
        $0.name.containsString(name)
    })
    return result.count == 0 ? nil : result[0]
}
```

Comment: That gives me the error - `'NSObject' does not have a member named 'name'` unfortunately.

Comment: @user3746428 Please show the declaration of `Ride` too

Comment: What is the type/definition of rideArray? Should be `var rideArray: [Ride]`

Comment: This solution is correct as well. Except for the `containsString` method not available in `String`. Please correct it and I will upvote this answer.